# MS Word VBA or VSTO Document Range to EnhMetaFileBits returns different result than display .. Any alternatives?

Tags: c#, vba, ms-word, vsto

### Background

I'm trying to make a procedure that convert selected area to image file.
My code uses `[Selection/Range].EnhMetaFileBits` to make the image of selection.

Mentioning any defect on this question is welcome.

### Problem

Most of the task was successful, except that the converted image has two problems.

1. Regardless of the page margin, if the table width is greater than a specific size, the right side of the image is sliced off.
2. Sometimes the result image is different from the displayed document view (as well as printed result).

#### problem 1 example image

[image: Source Document 1]

> Right table border line is missing.

[image: Result Image 1]

#### problem 2 example image

[image: Source Document 2]

> Rows 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 are single line text in the source, however they are two lines text in the result image.

[image: Result Image 2]

### What I want to know

I'm curios if there are any alternative other than `.EnhMetaFileBits` solution. I'm working on this in both VBA and VSTO so C#, C++ approach would be also appreciated.

Workaround using screenshot is not what I want.

### Code

```vb
Sub SaveAsEMFCurrentSelectionTable()
  Dim strFullName As String, strFileName As String
  Dim strBasePath As String, strFolderName As String
  Dim strImageName As String
  Dim strExtension As String
  Dim fso As New FileSystemObject
    
  strFullName = ActiveDocument.FullName
  strFileName = Split(ActiveDocument.Name, ".")(0)
  strBasePath = Split(ActiveDocument.FullName, ActiveDocument.Name)(0)
  Debug.Print strBasePath
  strFolderName = "Images-" & strFileName
  
  Dim oSelection As Selection
  Dim oRange As Range
  Dim tableNum As Long
  
  Set oSelection = Application.Selection
  Set oRange = oSelection.Range
  
  If oRange.Tables.Count > 0 Then
    tableNum = GetTableNum
    Debug.Print tableNum
    
    If Not fso.FolderExists(strBasePath & strFolderName) Then fso.CreateFolder strBasePath & strFolderName
    
    RangeToBytes oRange, strBasePath & strFolderName, "Table-" & Format(tableNum, "00#"), "emf"
    
  End If

End Sub

Private Function GetTableNum() As Long
  Dim oSelection As Selection
  Dim oTable As table
  Dim lTableNum As Long
  
  On Error GoTo Exception
  Set oSelection = Application.Selection
  Set oTable = oSelection.Range.Tables(1)
  lTableNum = ActiveDocument.Range(0, oTable.Range.End).Tables.Count
  
  GetTableNum = lTableNum 'RETURN
  Exit Function

Exception:
  Set oSelection = Nothing
  Set oTable = Nothing

  Select Case Err.Number
    Case Is = 5941
      Debug.Print "No table in selection"
      GetTableNum = -9999
      Exit Function
    Case Else
      MsgBox Err.Description, vbCritical, Err.Number
      Exit Function
  End Select
End Function

Sub RangeToBytes(ByRef selRange As Range, ByVal BasePath As String, ByVal fileName As String, ByVal Extension As String)
' GdipLoadImageFromStream :: WIN32API
' https://learn.microsoft.com/ko-kr/windows/win32/gdiplus/-gdiplus-image-flat

    Dim byteRange() As Byte
    byteRange = selRange.EnhMetaFileBits
    Dim bitImage
    bitImage = FreeFile
    ' Reference: Open-Put-Close : https://bettersolutions.com/vba/functions/put-statement.htm
    Open BasePath & "\" & fileName & "." & Extension For Binary Access Write As bitImage
    Put #bitImage, , byteRange() ' Test For Range -> EnhMetaFileBits -> Image
    Close #bitImage
End Sub
```

Comment: Can you copy that big an area by hand in Word.  Office copy/paste has some size limitations (that date bake to the OLE roots of COM).  If I remember correctly (from about 2002), you need to use an enhanced meta file, and do one more thing - which, sorry, I forget.  But, get it working by hand first

Comment: I have been doing this manually for eons beyond remembrance. In some cases a single table extends 300 or more pages.

Comment: This is how I work:  Print pdf > photoshop import > remove antialiasing and trim and grayscale > psd batch convert to tiff with monochrome CCITT4 >  batch insertion into Ms word doc > unify table images width > bring it to the original location in the doc

Comment: Now I clearly understand that `EnhMetaFileBits` of VBA has issues.  Copy and PasteSpecial  was the first attempt I got and didn't work. 
Widening the selection area seems beyond the scope of VBA.  And I can't adjust document size as the text and table position will be affected by doing so.  
Now I am investigating `gdi32` and `pscript5` dlls hoping to find what I can do.